# Does running CPU intensive tasks wear down my computer?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cpu-usage

I do a lot of statistical analysis in R (which uses a lot of CPU and RAM). Whenever I run my analysis, my laptop's fan runs at top speed. Monitoring tool shows that 1 of my cores runs at 100%, the rest normal (R doesn't use multi-core by default).

Whenever I do my work I feel instinctively worried about my machine, and I want to ask whether this instinct is actually validated?

My instinct could be wrong because:

- Using CPU a lot does not wear it down
- Computer fails much more often because of other components
- CPU may be worn down, but takes a long time

Comment: The main problem is heat. So long as everything is kept nice and cool, your CPU should last a long time. The problem is laptops are not known for being the coolest things.

Comment: B. computer is more likely to fail due to much heat and use because of other components that do not throttle when hot, have no sencors in them, are not silicon chips, and have a MTBF that drops a lot the hotter they are. Like capacitors. Proper maintance of the cooling, and care with insulating and blocking the vents. If you want to be overlay cautious you could potentially knock down turbo, to normal. Like in windows power properties you could set Max Processor to 99% and turbo stops working, reducing heat a small ammount.  Is it worth caring about? depends on you, Is it worth worry no :-)